# Расширение стандартного notification layout на Android

Tags: android

Необходимо в пуш нотификацию вставить barcode с небольшим заголовком. Оба элемента должны быть по центру. Но столкнулся с проблемой... Например если использовать BigPictureStyle, то некрасиво получается картинка при смене ориентации экрана да и растягивается бывает от края до края, что неприемлимо. 
Если использовать BigTextStyle, то можно юзать урезанный HTML, который казалось бы поддерживает , но показывает в пуше "[OBJ]" вместо картинки. Да и выравнивание по центру только в последнем 8 андройде завезли. 
Неужели нет способа элементарного форматирования текста в пуше с картинкой?
Похоже остается только использование кастомного layout'а. Я так понимаю нельзя в xml заинклудить базовые части стандартного системного пуша и нужно создавать весь целиком новый. Какие идеи, товарищи, по решению подобной проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

А чем же вас не устраивает кастомный layout? Здесь вы ничем не ограничены - в качестве примера кидаю свой кастомный лейаут - с картинкой, текстом, прогрессбаром и [блэкджеком со ...](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%85%D0%B8) :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_narrow_margin">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/wheel"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/notificationText"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="@string/placeholder"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_narrow_margin"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/DefaultHorizontalProgressBarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/notificationProgressBar"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_narrow_margin"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:progress="50"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Пихается через `RemoteViews`, приблизительно так:

```
 notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
 contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notification_layout);
 notificationBuilder.setContent(contentView);
 //blah-blah
```

Comment: Устраивает)) Казалось бы почему нет простого форматирования текста в стандартном layout'е. Был бы жир) А кастомный пуш отличается от стандартных material. В андройде 5 будет так смотреться рядом с системными пушами где лого слева, с >= 6 - лого справа. Да и в этом случае стоит задумать общую стилистику для всех пушей приложения. А всего этого можно было избежать просто передав html в Html.fromHtml

Comment: Забудьте свои вебовские хтмл - велкам в мир Android

Comment: ну пусть не html, а SpannableString. Ради картинки с текстом приходится делать кастомный шаблон нотификации. А с учетом того, что нотификации собираются в билдере, то отвалятся экшены-кнопки (придется их самому в дизайне прописывать), InboxStyle и другое. Лично меня дизайн пушей полностью устраивает стандартный андройдовский. Другие пуши придется на новый шаблон переписать, дабы стилистика была одна. Вся эта работа ради форматирования небольшого текста. Вот в чем боль)